# Bug in sklearn.linear_model LinearRegression?

Tags: scikit-learn, statsmodels

I'm following [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/sujitpal/statlearning-notebooks/blob/master/src/chapter3.ipynb) ipython notebook. It's a bit dated now and some API calls have changed. However, the maths should still work!

My Problem: I wonder why `sklearn LinearRegression` comes up with bogus results while `statsmodel OLS` has the same results as my guide.

The `sklearn LinearRegression` coefficients are 
**-3.05335819e+09,   3.05335819e+09**,   9.31299461e-02, -3.29341722e+00

While the `statsmodel OLS` results are:
**-1.17513710e-05,  -1.17509020e-05**,   9.23027375e-02, -3.27115207e+00

Unfortunately, to completely follow the example, it is necessary to export the "Boston" dataset from R.

I have created a [gist](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/dschien/66b8764c4ad1b7ed4f33) with the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
%matplotlib inline
# Data from R ISLR package - write.csv(Boston, "Boston.csv", col.names = FALSE)
boston_df = pd.read_csv("../../r/Boston.csv")
# fitting medv ~ lstat + I(lstat^2)
boston_df["lstat^2"] = boston_df["lstat"] ** 2
# fitting medv ~ poly(lstat,4). We already have lstat^2 and lstat from previous
boston_df["lstat^4"] = np.power(boston_df["lstat"], 4)
boston_df["lstat^3"] = np.power(boston_df["lstat"], 4)
X = boston_df[["lstat^4", "lstat^3", "lstat^2", "lstat"]]
y = boston_df["medv"]
reg7 = LinearRegression()
reg7.fit(X, y)
(reg7.intercept_, reg7.coef_)
```

which results in:

`array([ -3.05335819e+09,   3.05335819e+09,   9.31299461e-02, -3.29341722e+00])`

If I calculate the linear regression with statsmodel OLS, however :

```
# X = boston_df[["lstat^4", "lstat^3", "lstat^2", "lstat"]]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
# X = boston_df[[1., "lstat^4", "lstat^3", "lstat^2", "lstat"]]
ols = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
# ols.summary()
ols.params.values[1:]
```

I get the following results:

```
array([ -1.17513710e-05,  -1.17509020e-05,   9.23027375e-02,
    -3.27115207e+00])
```

Which is what is expected.

This is undermining my confidence in sklearn. I'm running this on OSX, in 
ipython 3.0.0, statsmodels (0.6.1), scikit-learn (0.15.2),numpy (1.9.2)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boston_df["lstat^4"] = np.power(boston_df["lstat"], 4)
boston_df["lstat^3"] = np.power(boston_df["lstat"], 4)
```

Here, why both are 4-th order poly-terms? Is this a typo or intention? Because from the result, the coefficients for 3-rd and 4-th order terms have exactly the same magnitude but just differ in sign. This is typically due to the multicollinearity problem that these two terms have almost perfectly positive correlation. In this case, both `sm.OLS` and `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()` are incorrect. It needs standard regularization treatment.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake I copied over. With this change, both APIs come to the same result.